# How to export a mesh modified with a PBR texture as OBJ, STL etc

Tags: rendering, mesh, export, pbr

complete Blender noob and really only looking to use Blender for a very specific application. I used a pretty simple tutorial to produce a 3D textured model.

The model looks great on Blender but exports as the original shape only with no change in geometry created by the PBR bumps. I've tried exporting in virtually all the allowed formats and they all export pretty similarly if at all.
[image: Render image of textured cube, what I want to export]

[image: Actuate OBJ output of the file no, 3D texture or bumps.]
I realise I am missing something fundamental here but how do I go about exporting the rendered shape as a mesh, bumps and all?

Any help much appreciated.

K

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @KennyMcK ask a question and I'll answer it :)

Comment: Thanks fir the guidance, points taken. Now how to edit my original question....

Comment: I think this tutorial was what I was looking for. It is for an old version of Blender but seems to work OK with a bit of searching in the menus for the right commands. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Zms6K9LxMQ

Answer (score 0):

The displacement node displaces the geometry of you cube in the render, however it doesn't actually change the geometry. if you look at the cube in the solid viewport you should notice it looks flat with no displacement.
Does your cube have any subdivision or dense geometry to displace?
The displacement map can be brought into geometry nodes and displace the mesh then apply the effect before export. Ask if you need me to clarify anything. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the post. You are right, the two essential parts I missed was creating some sub divisions in the UV Tool and then mapping the these to the  the texture. I found using a black and white Differenial texture was best for this. I ended up having to do a load of messing with the image and vertices to get the block work aligned correctly.